# AVAudioPlayer Crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, avaudioplayer

I have one problem with my `iOS` Application. I want to play multiple audio files (`.WAV`) using `IBAction` and `AVAudioPlayer`. Unfortunatelly the sound plays but if I play the sound many times, my application crashes. Maybe because memory is not properly released. Can you confirm my hypothesis and/or tell me how to fix this problem?

Here's my code.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString        *Path;
}

- (IBAction)Sound1;
- (IBAction)Sound2;
- (IBAction)Sound3;
- (IBAction)Sound4;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVAudioPlayer.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (IBAction)Sound1
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound1" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound2
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound2" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound3
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound3" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media play];
}

- (IBAction)Sound4
{
    Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound4" ofType:@"wav"];
    Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
    [Media play];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [player release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're allocating lots of AVAudioPlayer instances, but not releasing any of them.

What you need to do is set up your class as a `AVAudioPlayerDelegate`, remove the media instance variable from your class (instead simply create a new instance variable within your various IBAction methods) and implement the `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:` method as follows:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    [player release];
}
```

Finally, update your code to set your class as the delegate for each of the AVAudioPlayers you set up as follows:

```
...
Media = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:NULL];
[Media setDelegate:self];
[Media play];
...
```

By doing this, you'll ensure that you're releasing all of the AVAudioPlayer instances you create.

Comment: Hello! OK I removed the "Media" instance from my class and pasted your code but the app still crashes :C

Comment: @Aluminum Presume you've also removed the (now redundant) release from your de-alloc?

Comment: Yup I removed it now but it still crashes! Wait I'll update my code in this post so you can see my code better. Thanks for your help ^.^

Comment: @Aluminum My bad - you'll also need to set yourself as the delegate for the AVAudioPlayer - I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Aluminum Updated. I'd be tempted to check that it works before you get all carried away. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Media is never released... this is causing the memory leak. use SetterGetter methods, so that whenever new object will be allocated the previous object will be release.